# How to have a formula working in the background of a cell in Mircosoft Excel and allow a user to enter data?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am trying to create a spread sheet that will compile the data from multiple cells.

Essentially I want cell `A1` in `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` to reflect the same information input by the user without deleting the formula when data is input.

I need the users to be able to enter data into these cells but by using `=Sheet2!A1` or `=Sheet1!A1` I am creating a circular reference and also leaving the formula able to be deleted by the users.

Can anyone recommend a way of resolving this?

Comment: This is not how you should be using Excel...

Answer (score 3):

You can not enter data into a cell that contains a formula, while preserving the formula at the same time.

A solution is to have the user enter data in a different cell, then reference that cell in `A1` of both sheets.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it without a Macro. This code should work :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    therow = 1
    thecolumn = 1
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    cellrow = Target.Row
    cellcolumn = Target.Column
    If (cellrow = therow And cellcolumn = thecolumn) Then
        Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
        wks.Cells(cellrow, cellcolumn) = Target.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Open Macros with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>, double click *Sheet1* in the left side and paste the code on the right side. This code is executed in `Sheet 1`, so it copies changes in `Sheet1 A1` to `Sheet2 A1`.

Everytime there is a change in the worksheet this macro is executed. It checks if the cell changed is in row 1 and column 1 (cell A1) and then it copies the value in the same cell in *Sheet2*.

If you want to check changes from *Sheet2* to *Sheet1* also, then:

1. Double click *Sheet2* in the left side.
2. Paste the code on the right side.
3. Change the line `Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")`to indicate the new destination: `Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")`.

Right now, this macro uses the variables *therow* and *the column* to take the decision of copying the value to the other worksheet. At the beginning they are set to 1 in the lines `therow=1`and `thecolumn=1` meaning that we are interested in the cell **A1**. And further we check if the modified cell match with these values in the line `If (cellrow = therow And cellcolumn = thecolumn) Then`.

You can modify the values to customize it to your needs, even checking for a complete column or row, for example:

Changing the verification line to `If (cellcolumn = thecolumn) Then` will copy the changes that happen in the column that has the same value as the variable `thecolumn` no matter which row is it.

Other example:

Changing the verification line to `If (cellcolumn > thecolumn) Then` will copy the changes that happen in any column greater than the value of `thecolumn` no matter which row is it.

Comment: Thank you so much! this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Second question, I have this code working now, if I were to do this to multiple cells in 2 sheets, how would the code be entered in Macros?

A little background information, I have 1840 rooms that I have 2 work departments servicing. I would like the required cells to mirror the information into each depts. spread sheet to prevent double handling of tasks.
Currently both depts. use the one spread sheet but we are having the issue of each deleting the others data, hence why I am separating information but mirroring the spread sheets
Thanks

Comment: @Sean7147 I did a slight change to the code. Please use this new version from now on. I added in my answer an explanation of how you can modify the macro to copy more cells.

Comment: @Sean7147 While this may work, I would strongly consider whether this really is the best way to achieve your goal.  Is there a reason not to have a third sheet for input, and the other sheets refer to that master?